# How to use globally installed npm packages?

Tags: node.js, npm

When I run the following command,

```
$ cat main.js
#!/usr/bin/env node
// vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

const A = require('arcsecond');
const stringParser =  A.letters;

console.log(
    stringParser.run('hello')
);
```

I got some error like this.

```
$ ./main.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'arcsecond'
Require stack:
...
```

If I run the following command to install arcsecond locally, main.js will run correctly.

```
npm i arcsecond
```

But I don't want to install packages locally. I just want to use globally installed arcsecond package. How to let main.js use the globally installed arcsecond package? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you use require, it doesn't look at the global modules folder. Fix it by writing this in the (bash) terminal:
`export NODE_PATH=$(npm root -g)`

or by using the `requireg` package:
`var A = require('requireg')('arcsecond')`
But this requires that you've already linked requireg to the project path...
`npm link requireg`